# Apache Web Server が停止できない

Tags: apache

httpd.confで

```
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhost.conf
```

の `Include etc/extra/httpd-vhost.conf` の行に `#` をつけると正常にstop/startしますが、
コメントアウトするとstopしてもrunnning状態のままとなります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

コマンドで停止しようとすると、

```
$ apachectl -k stop
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com] does not exist
AH00526: Syntax error on line 29 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:
Invalid command 'CustomLog', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

とエラーログ が表示され、`/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`を開き該当箇所を見ると

```
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
```

となっています。この部分を触った覚えがないのと、何がエラーなのかが理解できません。

**実行環境**
Server version: Apache/2.4.33 (Unix)

どなたかご助言をして頂けると幸いです。
他に必要な情報があれば提示します。
宜しくお願いします。

Comment: 「コメントアウトする」は「`#`を削除して有効にする」の間違いではないですか？「コメントアウト」と「`#`を付ける」は同じ意味です。

Comment: コメントアウトは処理がされないようにするものですもんね。#を削除して有効にするの間違いです。単語ミス気をつけていきます。

Answer (score 1):

https.confの、

```
 # Virtual hosts
    Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

を、

```
 # Virtual hosts
    Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

にしたら正常にstop/startが出来るようになりました。
ありがとうございます。